# Count How Many Data Groups in File C++

Tags: c++, file, find, ifstream, getline

I have a data File like This;

```
  # Some Word n: 3   other word
  # Paarthunax is over age 100
  2.230  4.940  1.934  4.328
  3.340  4.470  4.023  3.546
  5.734  3.570  2.194  2.147
 

  # Some Word
  # Some other Words      123
  # Words a: 23    1.232323  : 12312321.123123    
  1.132  2.323  4.323  3.342
  1.131  1.233  5.232  4.432
  1.131  3.123  5.232  4.432

  1.131  1.123  4.232  5.442      
  1.134  3.333  2.423  4.312
  1.135  2.143  1.242  1.412
```

My data file contains so many data groups;
Every data group has description lines (Lines Starting with #). There might be empty lines in data groups, number is unknown. Unknown number of description lines of data groups(might be anything). Unknown number of empty lines between data groups, unknown number of data group rows.
Data lines might be in scientific notation (1.230E-01).

I don't want to read data from it I am already doing it manually with vectors. **I just need to count how many data groups in the file** but I cant figure out a reasonable pattern for this kind of file.

I defined a three function for this;

```
unsigned int get_number_of_lines(const string& file_name){
unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
string all_lines;
ifstream file(file_name);
while(getline(file, all_lines)){
    ++number_of_lines;
}
file.close();
return number_of_lines;
}
bool is_header(string line) {
    bool a = (line.find("#") != string::npos);
    return a;
}
int get_number_of_data_lists(string filename) {
int number_of_datalist;
ifstream stream(filename);
string line, subLine;
int i = 0;
while (i < get_number_of_lines(filename)){
    getline(stream, line);
    if(is_header(line)){
      ifstream sub_stream(filename);
      getline(sub_stream, subLine);
      while (is_header(subLine)){
            }
        }
    }
return number_of_datalist;
   }
```

**I can't get the rest of the get_munber_of_data_lists() I am open to any kind of advice.**

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Some advice, its not necessary, nor is it a good idea, to open the same file three times to answer this problem. You should be able to find the number of groups by opening the file once, and making a single pass through the file. Note you have three kinds of lines (not two) header lines, data lines and blank lines. The simple way to solve thing kind of problem is to think about it as a *finate state machine* (FSM). Do some reading on that and draw up a simple FSM that calculates the answer. Simple matter  to code that up and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a line by line read:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> database;
//...
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(file, text_line))
{
    // Ignore comment and blank lines.
    if ((text_line[0] == '#') || (text_line.empty()))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Process the data in the text line.
    bool is_data_line = true;
    while (is_data_line)
    {
        std::istringstream record_stream(text_line);
        std::vector<double> data_row;
        double number;
        while (record_stream >> number)
        {
            data_row.push_back(number);
        }
        database.push_back(data_row);
        std::getline(file, text_line);
        if ((text_line[0] == '#') || (text_line.empty()))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code reads a group of data.
The OP will need to modify the above code to handle multiple groups of data.

Comment: I am already doing that with other function.